# Generate csv files from a JSON

Tags: json, csv, jq

Unfortunately I have considerable difficulties to generate three csv files from one json format. Maybe someone has a good hint how I could do this. Thanks

Here is the output. Within `dropped1` and `dropped2` can be several different and multiple addresses.

```
{
  "result": {
    "found": 0,
    "dropped1": {
      "address10": 1140
    },
    "rates": {
      "total": {
        "1min": 3579,
        "5min": 1593,
        "15min": 5312,
        "60min": 1328
      },
      "dropped2": {
        "address20": {
          "1min": 9139,
          "5min": 8355,
          "15min": 2785,
          "60min": 8196
        }
      }
    },
    "connections": 1
  },
  "id": "whatever",
  "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

The 3 csv files should be displayed in this form.

```
address10,1140

total,3579,1593,5312,1328

address20,9139,8355,2785,8196
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decide to use jq, then unless there is some specific reason not to, I'd suggest invoking jq once for each of the three output files.  The three invocations would then look like these:

```
jq -r '.result.dropped1 | [to_entries[][]] | @csv' > 1.csv

jq -r '.result.rates.total | ["total", .["1min"], .["5min"], .["15min"], .["60min"]] | @csv' > 2.csv

jq -r '.result.rates.dropped2
 | to_entries[]
 | [.key] + ( .value | [ .["1min"], .["5min"], .["15min"], .["60min"]] )
 | @csv
' > 3.csv
```

If you can be sure the ordering of keys within the `total` and `address20` objects is fixed and in the correct order, then the last two invocations can be simplified.

Comment: Since I do not have the good knowledge I always thought jq would be better. Thank you. The first two commands work great. With the third I only have the problem that the addresses themselves are never the same and practically also represent a variable, as well as their value itself accordingly. Maybe I can manually pull them out of the json via sed and then use your third command via script accordingly for all variable addresses then. That concerns only the third part.

Comment: Please see update.

Comment: That's great, many thanks. In one case, if `dropped1` has more than one variable like `address10, address20` etc.) I have found a solution ```jq -r '.result.dropped1
 | to_entries[]
 | [.key]+[.value] 
 | @csv
'  my.json``` I think I have now understood some functions better thanks to your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using this library?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-to-csv-stream

```
npm i json-to-csv-stream
```

Comment: I just tried but unfortunately this is beyond my knowledge and am happy to get by with bash a little. I appreciate your support. Thank you